# Using AJAX with PHP to return remote server status

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

How do I use AJAX and PHP to return remote server's status? The only thing that I want is to make it run in background as it will make my webpage slower if I don't use AJAX.

I have the PHP curl snippet here which it pings the remote server (for example Google.com) and return its status:

```
<?php

function Visit($url){
       $agent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)";
       $ch=curl_init();
       curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url );
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
       curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
       curl_setopt ($ch,CURLOPT_VERBOSE,false);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3);
       curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
       curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);
       curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
       $page=curl_exec($ch);
       //echo curl_error($ch);
       $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
       curl_close($ch);
       if($httpcode>=200 && $httpcode<300)
            return true;
       else return false;
}
$load = "http://www.google.com";
if (Visit($load))
       //Website is up
else
       //Website is down
?>
```

I hope someone can guide me through this problem.

EDIT: Sorry for the unclear problem statement. How do I make a process run in background using AJAX, by using the PHP function I've provide above?

Comment: What's your actual question?

Comment: *"I hope someone can guide me through this problem"* what problem? is it not working? `if (Visit($load))
       Website is up` is definitely invalid php syntax.

Comment: AJAX runs in the background, so it should do what you want. The server code should echo whatever you want to be displayed, and the AJAX code should put the returned data wherever you want on the page.

Comment: Question edited. I haven't done it yet with AJAX though. I want the process to run in background instead of waiting for the whole page to load.

Comment: I've followed this tutorial, but it doesn't give what I want for a solution (or maybe because I'm a noob at this). Because mine has a conditional statement (server is up OR server is down), this tutorial doesn't. http://www.phptutorialforbeginners.com/2013/01/jquery-ajax-tutorial-and-example-of.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) replace your last if in your PHP with

```
header("content-type: application/json");
$status = array("status" => Visit($load)?"Website is up":"Website is down");
echo json_encode($status);
```

2)

```
$(function() {
  var tId = setInterval(function() {
    $.get("your php.php?url=...",function(data) { // or $.post
      $("#somecontainer").html(new Date()+":"+data);
    },"json");
  },60000); //test every minute
});
```

---

UPDATE:

webpage.html

[**Live Demo**](http://plungjan.name/SO/pollphp/pollserver.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var url = "http://www.google.com";
function checkIt() {
  $("#check").append("<hr/>checking "+url+" at "+new Date());
  $.get("check.php?url="+encodeURIComponent(url),function(data) {
    $("#check").append('<br/>Result:'+data.status);
  })
  .error(function(xhr, status, error) {
    $("#check").append("<br/>An AJAX error occured: " + status + "<br/>Error: " + error);
  });
}
$(function() {
  checkIt();    
  var tId = setInterval(checkIt,60000); //test every minute
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="check"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

check.php

- [Live Demo of http://google.com](http://plungjan.name/SO/pollphp/check.php?url=http://google.com)
- [Live Demo of http://googleeeee.coma](http://plungjan.name/SO/pollphp/check.php?url=http://googleeeee.coma)

:

```
<?php
$url = $_GET['url'];

class URIInfo { 
    public $status;
    public $error;

    private $url;

    public function __construct($url) {
        $this->url = $url;
        $this->setData();
    }

    public function setData() {
      $ch = curl_init($this->url);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
      curl_exec($ch);
      $this->status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
      $this->error = curl_errno($ch);

      //echo "http status:".$this->status."\nerror:".curl_errno($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
    }

    public function getStatus() {
        return $this->status;
    }
    public function getError() {
        return $this->error;
    }

    // Other functions can be added to retrieve other information.
}

header("content-type: application/json");
$uri_info = new URIInfo($url);
$error = $uri_info->getError();
if ($error!=0) {
  if ($error==6) $error="URL likely invalid:".$url;
  $status = array("status" => "Error occurred: ".$error);
}
else {
  $isUp = $uri_info->getStatus()==200;
  $status = array("status" => "Website is ". $isUp?"up":"down");
}  
echo json_encode($status);
?>
```

Comment: Look at AJAX code. It's json, he output directly the content. But I agree on one thing, JSON should be use.

Comment: You're serious? `echo json_encode(array("status" => "Website is up"));`

Comment: @mplungjan Because manually creating json is just... just no. That's what the json functions are there for.

Comment: @mplungjan Yes, awesome! (You almost got it). :D `array("status" => "Website is " . visit($load) ? "up" : "down");`

Comment: Technically, it's *faster* to write manually the JSON code when it's only that small... By faster I mean generation time and not the time to type the text.

Comment: So I've created a new file named `check.php` and put the process in there. I've also removed the conditional statement if-else. The JSON part should pass the URL to the JQuery using GET method. I've put the Jquery inside a `<script>` internally along with the JSON. And put `<div id="check"></div>` for the Jquery to populate the container. Is this the right way? It didn't work. It shows up error... Nvm, I've compiled it here: http://pastebin.com/B1hmPsYc

Comment: Heh, basically my problem other than this, was I don't know which code belongs to which file... :/

Comment: Okay, now, nothing showed up. But the rest of the HTML/PHP are fine. How do I debug the JSON to see if it is throwing anything?

Comment: Oh wait, it actually returned `Date()`:`data` since in the JQuery we declared `new Date()`. I guess you put it on purpose to see if it updates every one minute, and that works well. Now, how do I pass the `$status` from `check.php` to the JQuery back?

Comment: Hey thanks for the full solution. It worked really well, just need some tweaking to fit my needs :)

Comment: Is deleting comments a good practice here? I didn't know that, but I don't think I'll delete it because sometimes in the future, it may be useful for someone to learn about the mistakes. But hey, I hate being clutter too. He he

Comment: I was thinking more of the comments where you are clueless about what my code did ;) With the changes to my answer, they are irrelevant to the answer like the [rest of the comments beginning with this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18001560/using-ajax-with-php-to-return-remote-server-status/18001647?noredirect=1#comment26325026_18001647)

Answer (score 0):

You changed the question from the point where I first looked at it, so I didn't get to copy all your code, but here's one way:

First, complete your PHP (as others have noted):

```
$load = "http://www.google.com";
if (Visit($load))
    echo "UP";
else
    echo "DOWN";
```

Second, make your AJAX look something like this:

```
<head>
<script>
    function getdetails() {
        var xmlhttp;
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = " Website is " + xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        var URL = "URL-OF-THE-PHP-FILE-ABOVE";
        xmlhttp.open("GET", URL, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
    window.onload=function() {
      getdetails(); 
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="msg">Website Status</p>
</body>
```

But you probably don't want to make the AJAX call onLoad as you are looking for more efficiency.

I think this will help (if I understand your question correctly).

Comment: Yuck. If there is jQuery, use it for Ajax too

Comment: jQuery ALL the things xD

Comment: And inline body event handler is so w3schools

Comment: He originally provided non-jQuery source, hence the lack of jQuery. That was removed. Also, the inline body event handler is described in my reply as: "you probably don't want to make the AJAX call onLoad" - but again, he hasn't really provided much info as to how he wants to call the function... so I put it inline.

Comment: Hey Matt, I know using onLoad is useful in someway or another. Maybe it is not what I'm looking for. Thanks anyway. Upvoted :0

Comment: No, body onload is never useful. If you do not use jQuery, use `window.onload=function() { your onload code here }`

Comment: Yes, @mplungjan is absolutely correct re OnLoad. My code was solely intended to show the non-jQuery Ajax function, please ignore how it is called! :)